# How to execute tests as per their tag such as smoke or regression using pabot?

Tags: robotframework

I have many testcases written in Robot Framework for our android application.

For ex.

```
Verify Login functionality.

[Tags]  TC-1  Login.

Given Landing on Home page.

When Enter Login cred and passowrd.

Then User Lands on Homepage.
```

I use the pabot command to run this on 2 different devices at the same time:
pabot --argumentfile1 config-one.txt --argumentfile2 config-two.txt test.txt

All these times the pabot runs all the testcases present in the test.txt file whereas i only want to run those testcases which have 'login' tag.

Any idea how can i run only certain test cases using pabot which have a particular tag such as 'login'?

Answer (score 1):

pabot supports all robot command-line options, so you can use `--include` option ([Selecting Test Cases - By Tag Names](http://pabot%20--argumentfile1%20config-one.txt%20--argumentfile2%20config-two.txt%20test.txt)) to include only tests with a specific tag.

```
pabot --include login --argumentfile1 config-one.txt --argumentfile2 config-two.txt test.txt
```

I don't know if that's exactly right -  your example code shows a tag of `Login` but the body of the question mentions a tag named `login` (no trailing ".")

Comment: robot -i login testsuites/. -i is a shorthand for include

Answer (score 0):

I think, pabot options have to come before robot options. In your example the order  should be:

> pabot --argumentfile1 config-one.txt --argumentfile2 config-two.txt --include login test.txt